# Spock:Testing tightly Coupled Classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, spock

How can we Test a class X which is tightly coupled with another class Y.I am trying to write spock Test cases for the below class X, but I have trouble stubbing or verifying methods which are calling  class Y.Here I want to verify `Y.add` method called or not

```
class X {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) {
        val y = Y()
        y.add(a, b)
    }
}

class Y {
    fun add(a: Int, b: Int) {}
}
```

and also I would like have a Stub for Y which returns `add >> 10`

Answer (score 0):

In the case *that you showed*, don't acknowledge the existence of class Y at all, at least in the context of class X. Class X's use of class Y is an invisible implementation detail and not part of its public API (and in this case, there is only one possible correct implementation of `add`).

Answer (score 0):

You named it: **tight coupling!** So in this case the answer is always the same, I think I and others here must have written it dozens of times:

- Either you **refactor for loose coupling,** making the dependency injectable via constructor, setter or method parameter. Alternatively, you can use a DI framework such as Guice, Spring, CDI or similar.
- Or you **don't stub the dependency,** like Chrylis said. But then you might have to live with any **side effects** the call of `Y.add(..)` might have, which might be undesirable when trying to test `X` in isolation.
- Or you use additional, rather **"hacky" tools** like *PowerMock* or my own baby *Sarek*. Even though that works and I like my baby because it is such a nice toy to play with and see what it can do, I want to emphasise that this is the **least favourable** solution because it supports and cements bad design **instead of using TDD as a design tool** in order to guide you towards more maintainable, testable and better designed code. Only use it as a last resort if for some reason you have to use third-party classes with source code beyond your control. I am assuming that you control your class under test here, though, as is usually the case.

My recommendation: go refactor!

Answer (score 0):

Spock supports mocking and verifying of how many times was the method of mocked object called. The problem here is that in implementation above, there is no way for mocked instance of Y class to be accessed from inside of `X.sum` method.
If you rewrite X class in a way when instance of Y is passed in its constructor/as parameter of `sum` method:

```kotlin
class X {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int, y: Y) {
        y.add(a, b)
    }
}
```

...and make `Y` class & `add` method open, so that mock could be created and tested (may be done via [all open compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin) or directly):

```kotlin
open class Y {
    open fun add(a: Int, b: Int) {}
}
```

...then testing that `add` method of mocked `Y` class was called exactly once (with respectful arguments) is fairly easy:

```groovy
def testYAddWasCalledExactlyOnceWhenCallToXSum() {
    given:
       Y y = Mock()
       def x = new X()
    when:
        x.sum(1, 2, y)
    then:
        1 * y.add(1, 2)
}
```

just make sure you have [byte-buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) in you classpath

> and also I would like have a Stub for Y which returns add >> 10

It is possible, but at first you need to make `add` function to return `Int`:

```kotlin
open class Y {
    open fun add(a: Int, b: Int) : Int { return a + b }
}
```

then you again can use Mock:

```groovy
def testYAsStub() {
    given:
        Y y = Mock()
        y.add(1, 0) >> 10
    when:
        def sum = y.add(1, 0)
    then:
        sum == 10
}
```